# I am not able to change directory to local disk using terminal even though ls is listing them

Tags: 14.04, command-line, directory

It is showing directory doesn't exist again and again
here is what I am getting

```
v4_adi@v4:/media/v4_adi$ ls
F drive  Local Disk1
v4_adi@v4:/media/v4_adi$ cd F Drive
bash: cd: F: No such file or directory
v4_adi@v4:/media/v4_adi$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it this way

```
cd "F drive"
```

or

```
cd F\ drive
```

The space in the directory name should be quoted or escaped. Otherwise the command is interpreted as `cd F`.